# How is toArray working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var findDocuments = function (db, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection('tours');

    collection.find({ "tourPackage": "Snowboard Cali" }).toArray(function (err, second, data) {
        console.log(second);
        callback;
    })
}
```

How do we know that the documents from tours collection are being passed as in second argument.I do understand that we are using callback function but how to find out that the data passed by toArray function is in the second argument?

Comment: What Mongo API is this exactly? The mongo shell? Or some Javascript API?

Comment: It should be in second argument, what you are getting in console log for second argument? or just debug this code and check at run time what you are getting.

Comment: The [`toArray()` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) doesn't mention any arguments; where are you getting that code from?

Comment: @Chris G I have got this from lynda.com course.You can see the source code at https://github.com/synedra/learning_mongo/blob/master/Chapter3/03_01/Finished/index.js

Comment: @ArunKumar .I am getting null for first and third arguments.So my question is how do I get to know that the toArray function returns value in second argument of callback function.

Comment: @deceze I am using toArray API of mongodb

Comment: You can find one example at https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp too.Please search for toArray and you would get the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toArray` method is documented [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray):

> `toArray(callback)`
>
> Returns an array of documents. [..]
>
> ```
> Name      Type                          Description
> callback  Cursor~toArrayResultCallback  [optional] The result callback.
> ```

And the type of [`Cursor~toArrayResultCallback`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#~toArrayResultCallback) is defined thusly:

> `toArrayResultCallback(error, documents)`
>
> The callback format for results
>
> ```
> Name       Type            Description
> error      MongoError      An error instance representing the error during the execution.
> documents  Array.<object>  All the documents the satisfy the cursor.
> ```

Always read the API documentation, and it will tell you what to expect/what you need to conform to.